# Sum of Floor Series

Tags: summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I've been messing around with the floor function, and I am seeking to find a closed form of:
$$
\sum^n_{i=1}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\right\rfloor
$$
, or is there even one?
For reference, $n$ is an integer. I remember reading something about how this relates to the factors of $n$. I also reckon I'd need the gcd, but by just looking at the question I'm unsure how it could be related to. Any help or hints would be extremely useful.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function